# return all rows include non-existed row by assign "-" value

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a table "AA" below. Where the table structure created by this code

```
CREATE TABLE "AA" (
height character varying DEFAULT '-'::character varying,
class character varying NOT NULL,
gender character varying NOT NULL,
origin character varying NOT NULL
);
```

Then the data are

```
Height  class   gender  origin
162        1      m      a
169        1      f      a
172        1      m      b
169        2      f      b
171        2      f      a
```

Then I want to get query that contain combination of class (1, 3) and gender(m) and origin(a,b)
How can I achieve it if the result desired look like this

```
Height  class   gender  origin
162       1       m       a
172       1       m       b
-         3       m       a
-         3       m       b
```

I've try

```
Select COALESCE(height), class, gender, origin 
FROM AA 
WHERE class in ('1','3') and gender in ('m') and origin in ('a','b')
```

but it return only two rows above of second table.

then I try this one
//in php

```
<?php
    $class = array('1', '3');
    $gender = array('m');
    $origin = array('a', 'b');

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($class); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($gender); $j++) {
            for ($k = 0; $k < count($origin); $k++) {
                $query = 'select * from "AA" where ' .
                        " class = '" . $class[$i] .
                        "' and gender = '" . $gender[$j] .
                        "' and origin = '" . $origin[$k] . "' ";
                $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
                $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
                if (!$row) {
                    $row['height'] = "-";
                    $row['class'] = $class[$i];
                    $row['gender'] = $gender[$j];
                    $row['origin'] = $origin[$k];
                }
                if (is_null($row['height'])) {
                    $row['height'] = '-';
                }
                print_r($row);
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

a. Is there any effective technique to check zero-row-result and assign "-" value to specific coloumn?
b. Is there better do iteration in php or in sql and how to make the dynamic iteration if the field is more than 3 (scaling up)?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest part of this is getting all the lists correct.  The second is getting the `'-'` in the right place.  You can do the first part with a `cross join` and the second part by judicious use of `cast()` and `left outer join`:

```
select (case when t.height is null then '-' else cast(height as varchar(255)) end) as height,
       c.theclass. g.gender, o.origin
from (select 1 as theclass union all select 2) c cross join
     (select 'm' as gender) g cross join
     (select 'a' as origin union all select 'b') o left outer join
     table t
     on t.class = c.theclass and t.gender = g.gender  and t.origin = o.origin;
```

EDIT:

If `class` is a character, try:

```
select (case when t.height is null then '-' else cast(height as varchar(255)) end) as height,
       c.class. g.gender, o.origin
from (select '1' as class union all select '2') c cross join
     (select 'm' as gender) g cross join
     (select 'a' as origin union all select 'b') o left outer join
     table t
     on t.class = c.class and t.gender = g.gender  and t.origin = o.origin;
```

Comment: An error appear, what meaning with table t in there?
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "table"
LINE 6:      table t
             ^

Comment: @MuhammadHanifFahyuananto . . . `table` is supposed to be whatever table you are referring to, not the literal "table".  Your question doesn't specify the name of the table.

Comment: operator does not exist: character varying = integer 
 in this >>> on t.class = c.class  and t.gender = g.gender  and t.or... 
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (pgadmin's advise).

Then I try to cast the integer(c.class or g.gender or o.origin) into varchar it give error: failed to find conversion function from unknown to text

Comment: @MuhammadHanifFahyuananto . . . I can only guess what the types are in your table.  If they are different from the obvious types, then make the constants in the first three subqueries have the appropriate type.

Comment: I've edit the main question about the AA table is created. Then, I think the error is correct character varying=integer but how I can cast c.class or g.gender or o.origin into varchar data type?

Comment: when edited become this one: select '1' as class union all select '2'
it return error ERROR: failed to find conversion function from unknown to text
SQL state: XX000

Comment: @MuhammadHanifFahyuananto . . . I don't think `class` is reserved in Postgres, but you can name the variable something else.

Answer (score 0):

1 Read all existing values from sql into an associative array indexed by the class, gender and association.

2 Iterate over all possible combinations and then use `isset` to detect & fill missing combinations.

```
$query = "Select height, class, gender, origin FROM AA WHERE class in ('1','3') and gender in ('m') and origin in ('a','b')";

$result = pg_query($query) or die(pg_last_error());

while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //read in all existing values and index by class, gender, origin combo
    $key = $row['class'] . $row['gender'] . $row['origin'];
    $rows[$key] = $row;
}

$classes = array('1', '3');
$genders = array('m');
$origins = array('a', 'b');

//iterate over all possible combinations
foreach($classes as $class) {
    foreach($genders as $gender) {
        foreach($origins as $origin) {
            $key = $class . $gender . $origin;
            if(!isset($rows[$key])) { 
                //we're missing a value for the given class/origin/gender combo, so fill it in
                $rows[$key] = array(
                    'height' => '-',
                    'class' => $class,
                    'gender' => $gender,
                    'origin' => $origin,
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($rows);
```

Comment: FuzzyTree: in iterate over all possible combination step, how about the order the combination is not addressed (permutation)? can I iterate without addressed the order of field ?

Comment: @MuhammadHanifFahyuananto as long as the key order matches the order used in your indexed array (i.e. `$class . $gender .$origin` and `$row['class'] . $row['gender'] . $row['origin']`), the order you iterate does not matter because we are only interested in combinations (and not permutations)

Comment: So, it depend on first  order-combination in first $key for second $key in iteration. I see.